# Windows 10 keyboard shortcut for permantly deleting files without prompt or recyling bin

Tags: windows-10

Somehow I accidentally discovered the keyboard shortcut for deleting files permanently (no recycling bin) and without a confirmation prompt.

What is that keyboard shortcut and how do I disable it with extreme prejudice?

Comment: What is the Shortcut you have?  Shift-Delete permanently deletes files (no recycling bin) but does prompt.

Comment: The only shortcut documented by Microsoft is [`SHIFT+DELETE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-bypass-the-recycle-bin-when-deleting-files-36aa9c63-c12a-988f-43c4-e4347e2b2825)

Comment: It might be a shortcut provided by a third-party tool. Also, files on USB flash drives and on external disks, depending on file system, sometimes cannot be deleted to the Recycle Bin, though in most cases a warning is shown that deletion is permanent.